# defconstant with slime

Tags: compilation, constants, reload, read-eval-print-loop, slime

Every time I try to reload a file that uses `DEFCONSTANT` into the slime repl, it complains about me rebinding the constants.  How do I tell it I want it to do this, or what is a simple way to have slime exit and reload the inferior lisp process on recompiling files that use constants?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives:

- Move constants into their own file, which, hopefully, doesn't change very often.
- Change the constants into vars until you build a release candidate. Your Release TODO list should contain an item that tells you to convert these vars back into constants. In other words, temporarily change `DEFCONSTANT` to `DEFVAR`.